# Скрыть пароль от бд Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

Мне нужно скрыть пароль от базы данных. Я нашел, что можно через env файл, но у меня попросту не видит пароль. Если я буду напрямую вводить пароль в файле docker-compose.yml, то всё работает.
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  ShopWeb:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./Shope:/Shope
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=database
      - DB_NAME=Shop
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}  # Здесь используется переменная окружения DB_PASS
    env_file:
      - plaintext.env
    command:
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    image: shopeweb-shopweb:latest
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=Shop
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}  # Здесь также используется переменная окружения DB_PASS
```

plaintext.env

Comment: в CLI указывать надо файл `docker compose --env-file ./plaintext.env up -d`